# How to prevent vscode/ms-python from clearing test results?

Tags: python, testing, visual-studio-code

The results of python tests are cached for only a short time in the VSCode MS python extension.
Whether they succeeded or failed is only cached for a short while, and then they revert back to question marks again.

How to retain the results of the tests?

---

I think it has to do with this some logs that I see in the Output for "Python Test Log", which shows many (~30) of these lines:

```
python /home/.../.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.89148/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir /home/projectdir --cache-clear -s
```

In particular the `--cache-clear` is suspicious, however I don't know what is triggering these outputs.

So my question is: how to remove `--cache-clear` from the call? Or maybe something else is going on entirely?

Comment: I have the same question. It feels like this behavior is a bug, or would at least like an option to disable it. Just because test discovery runs, why should it clear the pass/fail status of the entire test suite?

Comment: That line is purely for test discovery, not execution. But if your results are not being left alone after execution completes then please open a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python and an animated GIF showing the issue will probably help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I too found myself in need of disabling this vscode behaviour.

I'm using pytest with the pytest-html plugin, and after all tests have run, as soon as i change a test file and save, this command is automatically run by vscode:

```
python c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir c:\Users\username\app\app-test-automation -s --cache-clear --html=report.html --self-contained-html tests
```

Which inevitably overwrite the .html test report.

I haven't found a way to remove the `--cache-clear` from the call.

BUT

You can disable the auto discovery of test (guilty of rerunning the command with the `--cache-clear` flag) by changing the following vscode setting:

[Picture of the setting from the vscode settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf3DT.png)

Comment: python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled